# Why doesn't FullText search find any result in some cases?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE word = "hello";

-- returns:
+----+---------+---------------------------------+
| id |  word   |               mean              |
+----+---------+---------------------------------+
| 1  | hello   | an expression of greeting;      |
+----+---------+---------------------------------+
```

But when I search with FullText index it returns nothing:

```
SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE MATCH(word) AGAINST("hello");

-- returns:
<0 row matched>
```

**Note:** Using `IN BOOLEAN MODE` is not useful either.

```
SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE MATCH(word) AGAINST("+hello" IN BOOLEAN MODE);

-- returns:
<0 row matched>
```

Why? And how can I make it working?

Comment: Are you sure that you actually have a full text index on the `dictionary` table?

Comment: Unable to reproduce the said issue on https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qvXh51RTLeNuNFAhNTaFUH/0 both versions works as expected